# Adicionar subdocumentos em documento - mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

Boa noite! Possuo o seguinte documento:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b21a4332a5e3333cc64a12f"), 
    "nome" : "João", 
    "sobrenome" : "Barbosa", 
    "cpf" : "12345678910", 
    "senha" : "Fabet@1010", 
    "viagem" : [
        {
            "empresa_origem" : "BRF", 
            "cidade_origem" : "Concórdia", 
            "uf_origem" : "SC", 
            "pais_origem" : "Brasil", 
            "empresa_destino" : "Santiago Foods", 
            "cidade_destino" : "Santiago", 
            "uf_destino" : "CH", 
            "pais_destino" : "Chile", 
            "peso" : "20000", 
            "carga" : "Queijo", 
            "placa_caminhao" : "MMM-9999", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b21a4332a5e3333cc64a130")
        }
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Percebam que existe o subdocumento vaigem.

No exemplo acima, existe o cadastro de um usuário e uma viagem. 
Gostaria de cadastrar mais viagens neste mesmo usuário, da seguinte forma:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b21a4332a5e3333cc64a12f"), 
    "nome" : "João", 
    "sobrenome" : "Barbosa", 
    "cpf" : "12345678910", 
    "senha" : "Fabet@1010", 
    "viagem" : [
        {
            "empresa_origem" : "BRF", 
            "cidade_origem" : "Concórdia", 
            "uf_origem" : "SC", 
            "pais_origem" : "Brasil", 
            "empresa_destino" : "Santiago Foods", 
            "cidade_destino" : "Santiago", 
            "uf_destino" : "CH", 
            "pais_destino" : "Chile", 
            "peso" : "20000", 
            "carga" : "Queijo", 
            "placa_caminhao" : "MMM-9999", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b21a4332a5e3333cc64a130")
        },
        {
            "empresa_origem" : "BRF", 
            "cidade_origem" : "Capinzal", 
            "uf_origem" : "SC", 
            "pais_origem" : "Brasil", 
            "empresa_destino" : "Santiago Foods", 
            "cidade_destino" : "Santiago", 
            "uf_destino" : "CH", 
            "pais_destino" : "Chile", 
            "peso" : "22000", 
            "carga" : "Carne Suína", 
            "placa_caminhao" : "MMM-9999", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b21a4332a5e3333cc64a131")
        }
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

É possível? Como posso fazer isso utilizando o mongoose? Sei que devo utilizar a _id do usuário "João" como parâmetro.

Comment: Olá Fred, eu queria saber como você gera esse _ID de cada item dentro do 'viagem', ou como você montou esse model/schema

Comment: @OdirleiBorgert o _id é um atributo gerado automaticamente. Veja este [guia](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition) no site do mongoose. Logo no início tem um exemplo de um schema com um subdocumento. Perceba que não existe a chave _id, isso porque, ela é gerada automaticamente. Mas caso queira, você pode declarar o _id manualmente também, como nesta [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose).

Comment: descobri o que faltava no schema, muito obrigado...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o operador [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push):

```
Collection.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: {viagem: OBJETO } }, options, callback)
```